# CoffeeScript lazy function implementation

Tags: coffeescript, lazy-initialization

I would like to something like this in JavaScript

```
var init = function () {
              // do some stuff once
              var once = true

              // overwrite the function 
              init = function () {
                 console.log(once)
              }

}
```

CoffeeScript adds another local var init to the initial init so the second init doesn't overwrite the first one

```
var init = function () {
              var init //automatically declared by coffeescript
              // do some stuff once
              var once = true

              // overwrite the function 
              init = function () {
                 console.log(once)
              }

}
```

Some tips for solutions / workarounds would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(**Update:** The answer below was accurate at the time, under CoffeeScript 1.0.1. It is no longer the case under CoffeeScript 1.1.0, which fixed this issue.)

Wow, this surprises me. The CoffeeScript

```
init = ->
  init = -> console.log once
```

declares both an outer `init` and an inner `init`. This strikes me as more likely a bug than a conscious language design decision—the compiler simpler evaluates the function before it evaluates the outer `init =` assignment. I've gone ahead and [filed an issue](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1188) on this.

Here's a workaround:

```
init = null
init = ->
  init = -> console.log once
```

Now there's only one `init`, the one with the outermost scope.

Comment: Thanks, works for me! Hard to tell if its a bug or not... Seems difficult to me to parse this one out.

Comment: @bzz Good news: This behavior has been changed in the just-released CoffeeScript 1.1.0!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is by design. You shouldn't rely on implicit globals. `init` is a property of the window/global object, so just reference it correctly:

```
window.init = ->
    var once = true
    window.init = ->
        console.log once
```

Comment: I posted this short snippet as an example. My question is why coffeescript doesn't recognize that init is already set. In my code init is a var declared inside of a function, it's not a global.

Comment: It's probably this way to keep the logic straight-forward. There would be a lot of edge cases involved in this kind of inferring, not to mention performance penalties. If you need some kind of currying you can embed plain js or reference properties directly. In different contexts you could also use @init but it wouldn't work here.

Comment: Trevor has filed this on CoffeeScript's, Github. You can read the reactions for a little more about the background. The link is in his answer.